# How to define custom binder variables in Wix installer project tool settings

Tags: c#, wix

hope somebody can help with this Wix installer question. I have edited my Wix project -> Tool Settings -> Additional Parameters -> Linker to include the following custom binder variable:

-dabcde=D:\pnh\Projects\WpfWix\WpfWix\bin\Debug

I can see this setting is present on the 'light' command line but the 'abcde' binder variable does not seem to be available when parsing this code:

```
<Component Id="WpfWix.exe" Guid="{D498BDED-57E8-4FED-AE7F-3C8C63ADEAA2}" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
    <File Id="WpfWix.exe" KeyPath="yes" Source="!(bind.abcde)\WpfWix.exe" />
</Component>
```

The '!(bind.abcde)...' placeholder is not replaced with the value set in the projects linker tool settings and I get the following error:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The system cannot find the file '!(bind.abcde)\WpfWix.exe'. Installer_WpfWix    D:\pnh\Projects\WpfWix\Installer_WpfWix\ApplicationFiles.wxs    6

I have had this method of defining custom binder variables working in the past and am not sure what I'm missing to get this working in my new project.

Thanks in advance,
Peter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an error in the `.wxs` file that is used by `candle.exe` in order to generate `.wixobj` files used by `light.exe`. In other words, you have to pass the arguments at the project build stage, not during linking.

In the `.wxs` source file you should be able to access your wpf project variables. In your case adding the following line before `<Product ... >` will point to the debug directory of your project:

```
<?define MyDirectory=$(var.WpfWix.TargetDir)?>
```

To get the path to the executable you can simply add the executable name

```
Source="$(var.MyDirectory)WpfWix.exe"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, this is one solution. After a bit more digging I came up with 2 others: <br />

1. Use -d<name>="<value>" setting in Wix project properties -> Tool Settings -> Compiler and reference in Wix XML using: $(var.<name>)

2. Use -b <name>=<value> setting in Wix project properties -> Tool Settings -> Linker and reference in Wix XML using: !(bindpath.<name>)